# Strategy of reusing mongoose models

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, request

I using mongoose with express.js

I designed server is create model dynamically.

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({ data: String }, { timestamps: true });

var model = mongoose.model(result.siteId, schema);

    var data = new model({
        data: JSON.stringify(req.body)
    });

    data.save(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).json({
                success: false
            });
        } else {
            res.status(200).json({
                success: true,
                data: result
            });
        }
    });
```

this is this part of create models. (data input part)
Once server get request, request's siteId is model's name. It is properly works.
but problem is using this created model.
I want this mongodb table. So i redeclare models but it not works.

```
var datas = mongoose.model('modelname', {data: String});
```

Once declare this model. 'data input part' (upper code) is not working and stopped server response and timeout message.
but other 'data input part' using another modelname is working.

i think mongoose stopped from redeclare model.
I want declare models other js file and use. but modelsname is must dynamic name.

What is proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar problem trying to reuse `Schema`s with different names and only managed to get it working by providing the collection name to `Schema` creation as well.

You can accomplish something similar by adding the [`collection` param](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection) to your Schema creation options.

But then you need different `Schema` objects for each `model`, so I suggest creating a function to retrieve models, based on a collection name, like

```
var buildModel = function(collectionName) {

  var schema = mongoose.Schema({ data: String }, { timestamps: true, collection: collectionName });

  return mongoose.model(collectionName, schema);
}

var model = buildModel(result.siteId);

var data = new model({
   ...
```